# Wordpress MPDF include Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, mpdf

I have never used mpdf before and I am trying to use it generate pdf vouchers in wordpress. I want to pull my advanced custom fields into the pdf template from the post where the pdf is being generated,I can't seem to do it though? What am i doing wrong?

This is the code from my functions.php file.

```
add_action('init', 'congres_redirect');

function congres_redirect()
{
    if (isset($_GET['offer'])) {
        view_conferinta();
    }
}

function view_conferinta()
{
    $post_id = false;
    $vouchRestName = get_field('restaurant_name', $post_id);
    $output = '<html>
    <head><title>Voucher Download</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
    <style>
    .printable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .printable td {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:5px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>';

        $output .= '<div style="">Restaurant Name: '.$vouchRestName.'</div>';

        $output .= ' 
    </body>
    </html>';
    require_once __DIR__.'/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
    $mpdf->Output('restaurant-voucher.pdf', 'I');
    //$mpdf->Output($pdfheader.'.pdf', 'D');
    exit;
}
```

If there is an easier way to achieve this please let me know, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if there is any global post id available already in the `init` hook.

Comment: You’re checking if `$_GET['offer']` is set there, are you trying to use that to pass the post ID via URL? If so, then you should probably also actually _use_ that value inside your function then, instead of setting `$post_id = false;` and passing that into the `get_field` function …?